# How do I open archive files from the command line?

Tags: 12.04, archive

I need to open archive files from the command line.  I can use things like "jar tvf" to list the contents, but I'd like to get the explorer view.  What is the name of the application that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file-roller is the name of that program.